# Joomla query pick value

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$id = $user->get('id'); // or $user->get('id');
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName('membership'))->from($db->quoteName('#__jomcl_adverts'))->where($db->quoteName('id')."=".$db->quote($id));

$db->setQuery($query);
$memb = $db->loadObjectList();
```

this is the result when I echo 'query'

```
SELECT `membership` FROM `#__jomcl_adverts` WHERE `id`='7221'
```

I am using Joomla, I want to pick the value in Membership column inside Adverts table.

I need the code to follow the if condition if the value inside membership is 5.

```
<?php if($memb['membership'] == "5") { ?>
<div id="jomclpstbtn<?php echo $module->id; ?>" class="jclasspstbtn <?php echo $params->get('moduleclass_sfx'); ?>">
<div class="jclasspstbtnblock">
    <a class="jomclbtnlink" > 

        <span class="jomclbtnname">Advert Already Posted</span>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Just like this.

But I guess the query isn't picking value from Membership Column.

Comment: can you describe the table `#__jomcl_adverts` ?

Comment: That table has various columns, including the userid. So the query matches the user id of the current login session with the userid mentioned in adverts table, I have showed the echo results for that. When the userid matches it should select the value of 'membership' column inside the adverts table and follow the if condition. if the value is 5 then should display the div as mentioned inside if condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically `loadObjectList()` returns an indexed array of PHP objects from the table records.

so your if condition should be :

`<?php if($memb['0']->membership == "5") { //for first set of result ?>`

eg : `$row['index']->membership // e.g. $row['2']->membership`

you can read in more details [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#loadObjectList.28.29)

Comment: Thing is if i print_r($memb) it doesn't display any result, it just shows 'Array()'

Comment: can you try `print_r($memb[0])` or attach a screendump.

Comment: print_r($memb[0]);
exit();

did this it showed a blank screen.

Comment: dont use `exit();` use joomla's API `jexit();`, it seems that there is issue with sql query did you try running this select statement in your DB directly ? with help of phpmyadmin or mysql workbench tool, try doing that and check the result for above statement.

Comment: jexit(); didn't create a difference though.

I just want to match the user id of current session with the user id inside adverts table, when it matches it should pickup the value of Membership column and follow if condition below.

Comment: did you try running that SQL in your DB directly to see its output ?

Comment: this would be more easy over teamviewer :D